# Spree assets in production mode

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, assets, spree

Wondering how to configure Spree to handle assets properly on the production server. Using `Spree 2.4.2` with `Rails 4.1.8`.

Per the documentation, I have added all of my assets to the vendor folder. I have also correctly configured my `all.css` and `all.js` files. In development mode, everything works fine. Site looks great, no errors, all js and css load fine. When entering the production server, the css and js files are not found. The site is looking for them in the public folder naturally.

I have not configured anything specific. Default Spree setup should be handling my assets. Some research into the Rails Asset Pipeline led me to run:

```
rake assets:compile
```

This compiled a ton of stuff, including an `all-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css` and an `all-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.js` file.

However, spree is still looking for them in `stylesheets/spree/frontend/` while the compiler put them in `assets/spree/frontend/`

Images is a whole different story...

Thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?

On a side note, I copied my assets (including the compiled css and js files) to the location that spree was looking for them, just so I could see if everything worked on the production server. It worked great the first time I viewed a page. The second time I viewed the same page however, there were obvious css issues. It was almost as if the css had changed once it was cached. Any insights on this?

Answer (score 0):

did you add the top-level assets to config.assets.paths in your application.rb ? I happen to know that the default Spree install doesn't have this.

Also, are you deploying on Heroku? There are special considerations for Heroku.

As well, read the Asset Pipeline guide and make sure you understand as much of it as you possibly can. There's nothing special about Spree that makes it different from another Rails app in terms of the Asset Pipeline

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html